# java help distance between two points java POO

Tags: java, oop, distance

The problem `A` and problem `B` are meant to be in the same code.

**Problem A:**

> Implement the Ponto class constructor that takes two parameters
> integer values ​​with the values ​​of attributes x and y, respectively.

> Implement another constructor for the Ponto class that takes nothing for
> parameter, the constructor initializes the class attributes (x and y) to zero.
> Note that here we use static polymorphisms.*

**Problem B**

> Implement a method that checks whether two points are equal, that is,
> check if two points have the same values ​​for x and y, one of the points
> will be passed implicitly in the method call and another
> traditional method as a parameter. Then implement the method that
> calculates the distance between two points, for which the object that invokes the method is
> considered a parameter (implicit) and another Point object is passed by
> parameter to the method (explicit).*

I couldn't understand how I would relate the only two variables to produce something like "x(10,10) and y(1,4)" then calculating the distance of it, checking if they have the same value and finally the constructors.

**teacher's insight code**

```
public class Ponto {
 private int x,y;

//Constructers

//methods
}
```

**Thats is what Ive produced**

```
package pontos;

public class Ponto {
    private int x,y;

    
    //CONSTRUTOR  
    public  Ponto() {
     x = 0;
     y = 0;
            
    }
    

    //CONSTRUTOR COM PARÂMETRO 
    Ponto(int x_, int y_){
        this.x = x_;
        this.y = y_;
        
        if (x == y) {
            System.out.println("Seus pontos são iguais!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Agora você tem distância haha");
        }
            
                
    }


    
    //MÉTODOS
        
    
    
    //GETTER SETTER
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }


    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }


    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }


    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
```

**the object>**

```
package pontos;

public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double dist;
        
        Ponto xy = new Ponto(10,1);
        Ponto xy2 = new Ponto(5,10);
        
        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xy2.getX()-xy.getX() , 2) + Math.pow(xy2.getY() -xy.getY() ,2));
        
        System.out.println("** Resultado da distância do ponto X e Y **");
        System.out.println("eeee: " + dist );
        System.out.println("Olha só: " + xy );

    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and remove all fluff text that has nothing to do with the problem itself, text about how tired you are, how many days or hours you've worked on the problem, text that does not help us understand your code or your problem, and replace it with text that actually *does* help us to understand both the current code, the current problem and your main question. It's hard to find the details in all that junk in there, to be honest and this is greatly hurting your question.

Comment: I've tried to remove some of the junk...

Comment: Im sorry, I did not sleep for 20 hours straight. Ive tried to make it good by adding tittle for the eye to follow.

Comment: You don't need to "find a solution".  The purpose of homework is not the solution.  The purpose is to learn how to program.  And you can't program if your brain is fried because you haven't slept for 20 hours, what you need first is sleep.  Then you need to try and solve the problem yourself rather than wasting time looking for solutions.

Comment: Hint: Testing if two `Ponto` are the same location should be straight forward.  Get the `x` and `y` values for the respective `Ponto` and compare them.  You could write a method that takes two `Ponto` objects as parameters, compares them, and returns a `boolean` to say if they are the same or not.  But the task says to make the method a method of `Ponto` ... and to compare `this.x` and `this.y` with the `x` and `y` of a second `Ponto`.

Comment: Thats the problem. Everything was okay until I got to answer this specific question. Ive asked everywhere, tried to learn all the way and I still couldnt understand. Now im here, asking for help because I couldnt solve it by myself. 

Im not here for 'not learning' I do want to learn and understand where im failing, sometimes the answer gives me more insight than the questions by doing reverse.

Comment: Do you understand what `this` is?  What an *instance* method is?

Comment: I was testing in my code what would happen by doing multiple stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about where are you jammed. You are being asked to implement two methods of the `Ponto` class (that's what the implicit pass of the first point means).

Try someting like the following:

```
public class Ponto {

    ...

    public boolean equalsTo(Point other) {
        return this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y;
    }

    public double distanceTo(Point other) {
        return Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(this.x - other.x , 2)
          + Math.pow(this.y - other.y , 2)
        );
    }

    ...

}
```

The use of `this` keyword, together with the definition of the methods inside the `Ponto` class is what is meant by the use of one of the points as *implicit*, and the use of the `other` point as parameter of the method as *explicit*.

Then you could call this methods within other parts of the program by

```
public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double dist;
        boolean equal;
        
        Ponto xy = new Ponto(10,1);
        Ponto xy2 = new Ponto(5,10);
        
        dist = xy.distanceTo(xy2);
        equal = xy.equalsTo(xy2);
        
        System.out.println("** Resultado da distância do ponto X e Y **");
        System.out.println("eeee: " + dist );
        System.out.println("Olha só: " + xy );
        System.out.println("They are the same point: " + equal);

    }

}
```

Comment: Also look at the javadoc of `Math.hypot` (hypothenuse).

Comment: ouh Alfredo, thanks.  I was stuck at relating the given question to the actual programming. How Problem B would relate to problem A in the code.